# Multiple HTML5 Video Tags on 1 page

Tags: html, html5-video

I have a web page where the top of the page is a fullscreen div with a background of a video. I also have, further down the page another video (for testing purposes the same video).

I have an interesting scenario to figure out...

- Video 1 (at the top of the page) works perfectly on Firefox, Safari, Chrome, IE
- Video 2 (half way down the page) works great on Firefox, Safari and IE. **NOT Chrome**

Due to the nature of my job I have to ensure that the websites I develop are browser safe. Does anyone know why 1 video would be working in Chrome but the other won't?

**AT TOP OF PAGE**

```
<video id="video" poster="img/poster.png" loop muted class="video-js vjs-default-skin" preload="none" width="100%" height="100%" data-setup="{}">
    <source src='img/video.mp4' type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

**HALF WAY DOWN PAGE**

```
<video  id="s-video" poster="img/poster.png" loop muted class="bg_video video-js vjs-default-skin" preload="none" width="100%" height="100%" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="img/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

I also have this bit of DOM Javascript at the bottom of my page

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('video').play();
    document.getElementById('s-video').play();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess (as there is not so much info here) there is a problem with the data being ready soon enough when `play()` is executed.

You could try to change the following things:

- I the tags themselves, change `preload` to use `auto`
- In the JavaScript, add listeners to the elements for the `canplay` event

Example:

```
<video id="video" poster="img/poster.png" loop muted class="video-js vjs-default-skin" preload="auto" width="100%" height="100%" data-setup="{}">
    <source src='img/video.mp4' type="video/mp4"/>
</video>

<video  id="s-video" poster="img/poster.png" loop muted class="bg_video video-js vjs-default-skin" preload="auto" width="100%" height="100%" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="img/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

and

```
<script>
    var video1 = document.getElementById('video');
    var video2 = document.getElementById('s-video');

    video1.addEventListener("canplay", start);
    video2.addEventListener("canplay", start);

    function start() {this.play()};  // "this" = current element calling
</script>
```

**Update**

This could also work if you want to have `preload` set to `none`:

```
<script>
    var video1 = document.getElementById('video');
    var video2 = document.getElementById('s-video');

    video1.addEventListener("canplay", start);
    video2.addEventListener("canplay", start);

    function start() {this.play()};  // "this" = current element calling

    video1.load();  // start loading video (metadata + data)
    video2.load();
</script>
```

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg, I don't really understand why this wouldn't work with preload="none", and without waiting for "canplay". Calling play() should load the media if it hasn't started to load already. The fact that it's two copies of the same video is suspicious. I wonder if this could be related to [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31014), which was supposedly fixed.

Comment: @aldel Perhaps you're thinking about load()? Try invoking load() instead of using preload=auto. You must in any case listen for canplay (or canplaythrough). to invoke play(). Answer updated.

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg, no, not thinking of load(). Looking at [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#dom-media-play), I think play() should start the media loading if it hasn't started already. Also the fact that one of the two video elements works with just a play(), plus the fact that both video tags work in other browsers, reinforces my suspicion that this is a Chrome bug.